# Magento Product add api not working

Tags: php, api, magento

For some reason I can't get the Magento API to add a new product. There are a few things the documentation do not make clear.

**How do I get the website ID? there is only one site and one magento cart so shouldn't that default?**

Below is my code the php variables are being set earlier in the script. Am I missing anything?

```
$result = $client->call($session, 'catalog_product.create', array('simple', $attributeSet['set_id'], $ItemNmbr, array(
    'name' => $Model,
    'description' => $ItemDesc,
    'weight' => $Weight,
    'status' => '1',
    'visibility' => '4',
    'price' => $UnitPrce,
    'tax_class_id' => 1,
    'meta_title' => $Model,
    'meta_description' => $ItemDesc
)));
```

This is the error I am getting:

```
Fatal error: Uncaught SoapFault exception: [1] Internal Error. Please see log for details. in myweb_servicescript.php:55 Stack trace: #0 myweb_servicescript.php(55): SoapClient->__call('call', Array) #1 myweb_servicescript.php(55): SoapClient->call('8682ab614bb8a30...', 'catalog_product...', Array) #2 {main} thrown in myweb_servicescript.php on line 55
```